# Low level disk I/O in python

Tags: python, io, disk

Is there a way to perform low level read/write to disk using python. For example, read 1 byte starting at some given position.

Comment: Open the raw disk device as a file, seek to the position, and read.

Comment: You should google a question and come up with some solution before asking a question here. Googling "read byte from file python" just gave me a handful of links explaining how to do it, including StackOverflow explanations, as well as the documentation on the Python site with what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just open disk path for binary read ("rb"), `seek` to position and then `read(n)` where n is number of bytes.